# Android Java SQLite Select

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a query that gets a `LEFT JOIN` between 2 tables and everything works successfully and visualize the data in a ListView.

But now I need to fetch data from another table too, so I should combine these two queries. I'm stuck. Can you help me? thanks

```
String sql1 = "SELECT c._id, c.field1, c.field2, c.field3, SUM(g.field01), SUM(g.field02), g.field03 " +
    "FROM Table1 c LEFT JOIN Table2 g ON (c.field1  =  g.field03) GROUP BY c.field1";

String sql ="SELECT _id, riserva_1, riserva_2, SUM(riserva_3) FROM riserva  GROUP BY riserva_1";
```

Comment: In what manner do you wish to combine then? A simple example of the data you have and the end result you require from it would help.

Comment: the field `riserva_1` is equal to `(c.field1  =  g.field03)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood right, but here is my solution. this will join the result of you first left join with the riserva table on the condition you put as comment and then it groups it by field01 of table1 and then riserva_1 of table riserva. Hope it works. 
Note: I am not adding all the fields you should figure out that part by yourself, ok?

```
String tables = String.format(
                    "(%s LEFT JOIN %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s) INNER JOIN %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s",
                    Table1,
                    Table2,
                    Table1,
                    field1,
                    Table2,
                    field03,
                    riserva,
                    Table1,
                    field1,
                    riserva,
                    riserva_1 );
String columns[] = new String[] { String.format(
                    "%s.%s, %s.*, SUM(%s.%s) AS %s",
                    riserva,
                    riserva_1,
                    Table1,
                    Table2,
                    field01,
                    sumefiles01 ) };
String groupBy = String.format( "%s.%s, %s.%s", Table1, Table1, riserva, riserva_1);

// you dont have where clause so ignore next 2 lines
//String whereClause = String.format( "%s.%s <> ?", Table1, Table1 );
//String whereParameters = new String[] { "" };

Cursor cursor = database.query( tables, columns, null, null, groupBy, null, null, null );
cursor.moveToFirst();
if(!cursor.isAfterLast(){
// do something
}
```